# In react-router V4.x, how to pass parameters when going back

Tags: reactjs, react-router

- React-router V4.x
- React.js

I just have 2 pages called 1st page and 2nd page, 1st -> 2nd; I want to go back to the 1st page with some parameters, so I can display different views.

In [official docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history/history-is-mutable), I just saw `go` or `goBack` functions, unfortunately, it doesn't support passing a parameter!

So, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

use route params for 1st page and assign 1st page url with data to back button of 2nd page. dont use go back or back.